# Using compiled Swift 2 in iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, xcode7, ios9

Is it possible to write a library in `Xcode 7 / Swift 2` and used it's compiled version in older `XCode 6.4 / iOS 8`?

We've already build a big library in Swift 2 and now we need to use in old code :|

Answer (score 2):

Yes you **can** use the two code bases together, if the old project is in Objective-C.
No, you **cannot** do it in Xcode 6.4.
No, you **cannot** use Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0 in the same project.

IMO, the best route is to use code migration assistant to migrate the old code to Swift 2.0. (A great exercise, too.)

Comment: Thanks, can you lead me to a tutor for building/compiling libraries?

Comment: Why would you need that? You have already build the library in Swift 2 :-).

Comment: I mean which files I should copy to Swift 1.2 project :)

Comment: I have amended my answer with this new information.